Unable to run programe using gocv due to missing opencv module
I have installed gocv and opencv to complete media related work.

Opencv version 4.9.0.80
Gocv -> gocv.io/x/gocv v0.36.1
And I am running small programme for testing

func main() {
    // Get the predefined Aruco dictionary.
    arucoDict := gocv.ArucoDictionary.GetPredefinedDictionary(gocv.DICT_6X6_250)

    // Print the name of the dictionary.
    fmt.Println(arucoDict.GetName())
}

But it is not running giving below error
 

    go run shaky.go 
    # gocv.io/x/gocv
    In file included from aruco.cpp:1:
    aruco.h:12:13: error: ‘aruco’ in namespace ‘cv’ does not name a type
       12 | typedef cv::aruco::Dictionary* ArucoDictionary;
          |             ^~~~~
    aruco.h:13:13: error: ‘aruco’ in namespace ‘cv’ does not name a type
       13 | typedef cv::aruco::DetectorParameters* ArucoDetectorParameters;
          |             ^~~~~
    aruco.h:14:13: error: ‘aruco’ in namespace ‘cv’ does not name a type
       14 | typedef cv::aruco::ArucoDetector* ArucoDetector;
          |             ^~~~~
    aruco.h:21:1: error: ‘ArucoDetectorParameters’ does not name a type
       21 | ArucoDetectorParameters ArucoDetectorParameters_Create();
          | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    aruco.h:22:58: error: variable or field 
    ‘ArucoDetectorParameters_SetAdaptiveThreshWinSizeMin’ declared void
           22 | void ArucoDetectorParameters_SetAdaptiveThreshWinSizeMin(ArucoDetectorParameters ap, int adaptiveThreshWinSizeMin);
              |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        aruco.h:22:58: error: ‘ArucoDetectorParameters’ was not declared in this scope
        aruco.h:22:86: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
           22 | void ArucoDetectorParameters_SetAdaptiveThreshWinSizeMin(ArucoDetectorParameters ap, int adaptiveThreshWinSizeMin);

    .
    .
    .

    aruco.cpp:281:9: error: ‘cv::aruco’ has not been declared
      281 |     cv::aruco::generateImageMarker(dict, id, sidePixels, *img, borderBits);
    
    aruco.cpp:281:36: error: ‘dict’ was not declared in this scope
      281 |     cv::aruco::generateImageMarker(dict, id, sidePixels, *img, borderBits);
                                           
    aruco.cpp: At global scope:
    aruco.cpp:284:1: error: ‘ArucoDictionary’ does not name a type
      284 | ArucoDictionary getPredefinedDictionary(int dictionaryId)


Please Guide me ...

Did you follow https://gocv.io/getting-started/? Does the example output the version numbers as in the guide?
